# How to specify Google Guice path to implementation?

Tags: java, maven, ant, module, guice

I have moved my solution from ant to maven. Earlier I have two jar files after build - API and IMPL jar, and this jars was depend to each other, because ant does not forbid it.
Maven forbids cross-dependensies, but I have some Guice modules with IMPL classes in API jar. I can't move this classes to API, and can't change this modules. I want to find a solution like this:

```
bind(BitTrackUtils.class).
        to(BitTrackUtilsBase.class).
        in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

BUT with **path to implementation** instead "BitTrackUtilsBase.class". Is solutions except reflection exists? Maybe, Guice annotations or something..
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you keep your modules in the API JAR? If someone will want to write their own implementation of your interfaces, it will have to be imported along with Guice modules, and Guice dependencies as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how API and implementations are usually designed when you actually want to decouple the two from the beginning. I think that you should try to go this way instead of trying to fix your clunky circular dependency. Classes are either part of the API or they are not. The following schema makes that clear. And the API can be built first without requiring anything from the implementation. So Maven will be very happy to oblige your build.

## magic-api.jar

This JAR contains your API and nothing more. Note that there are some classes here you'll find usually don't belong to an API (the provider interface, for instance), well they do.

```
magic-api.jar/
└─ magic/
   ├─ spi/
   |  └─ MagicProvider.class
   ├─ Magician.class
   └─ Trick.class
```

### Trick.java

Your core API.

```
public interface Trick {
  void prepare();
  void execute();
}
```

### MagicProvider.java

This is your provider, a SPI (Service Provider Interface), that allows your implementations to be registered. This class is exposed (public), yes, but in another package and documented saying something along "this is for SPI only". You're using Guice, well, know that [Guice has a SPI](https://github.com/google/guice/tree/master/core/src/com/google/inject/spi) (okay, somewhat different in regards to the way implementations are provided, but the core idea is the same).

```
public interface MagicProvider {
  Trick getTrick();
}
```

### Magician.java

This class will allow you to get access to `Trick`, through the SPI. This has a basic example where only one `MagicProvider` will be used throughout the whole run, well, you can be creative and look for implementations until you find one that suits you. For instance, if you had `getTrick(String trickName)` you could loop through all the `MagicProvider` until one can provide the trick named `trickName`.

```
public class Magician {
  private static final ServiceLoader<MagicProvider> providers = ServiceLoader.load(MagicProvider.class);

  public static Magician getInstance() {
    for(MagicProvider provider: providers) {
      if (provider != null) {
        return new Magician(provider);
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No implementation found for MagicProvider");
  }

  private final MagicProvider provider;
  private Magician (MagicProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }
  public Trick getTrick() {
    return provider.getTrick();
  }
}
```

## magic-impl.jar

This JAR is a bit different: there are no mentions of the API outside the imports. So here, the responsibility is only to implement interfaces from the API. When that's done, just write down the Provider name in a file named exactly as the Provider class name (in our case, `magic.spi.MagicProvider`). That file must be in the folder `/META-INF/services/` of your JAR file. That's basically your only constraint to register your provider.

```
magic-api.jar/
├─ copperfield/
|  ├─ spi/
|  |  ├─ Copperfield.class
|  |  └─ CopperfieldModule.class
|  └─ HideTheStatueOfLiberty.class
└─ META-INF/
   └─ services/
      └─ magic.spi.MagicProvider
```

### Copperfield.java

This is your SPI implementation. Usually, it's public, with a public constructor so that `ServiceLoader` can load it properly. This is where you'll use Guice, and not in the API.

```
public class Copperfield implements MagicProvider {
  private final Injector injector;
  public Copperfield() {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new CopperfieldModule());
  }
  public Trick getTrick() {
    return injector.getInstance(Trick.class);
  }
}
```

### CopperfieldModule.java

Your standard, basic Guice module.

```
class CopperfieldModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(Trick.class).to(HideTheStatueOfLiberty.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
  }
}
```

### HideTheStatueOfLiberty.java

This is your real implementation of your API.

```
public class HideTheStatueOfLiberty implements Trick {
  @Override public void prepare() {
    System.out.println("Now you see the Statue of Liberty.");
  }
  public void execute() {
    System.out.println("Now you don't!");
  }
}
```

### magic.spi.MagicProvider

Yes, that's the full name, no other extension (no `.txt`, `.java`, `.class`, ...). The name is also the fully qualified Java name (meaning "with package") of the Provider interface. This is just a text file with the following content. Nothing more, nothing less. Make sure to place it in `/META-INF/services/`. You can optionally add comments with the `#` symbol

```
# Register Copperfield as a provider
copperfield.spi.Copperfield
```

## Usage

This will be present somewhere in your API client. Note that you see here only classes from the API!

```
Magician magician = Magician.getInstance();
Trick trick = magician.getTrick();
trick.prepare();
trick.execute();
```

### Result

```
Now you see the Statue of Liberty.
Now you don't!
```

## Notes

1. If you don't like to declare a file in `/META-INF/services/` yourself, you could look at the excellent [AutoService](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) (by Google too). All you'd need to do in that case is to add `@AutoService(MagicProvider)` to the `Copperfield` class and forget about the "extensionless" file.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: But do you know how I might to put my modules from IMPL module to injector in API module by GOOGLE GUICE SPI?

Comment: @MagentaMill That defeats the principle of separation between an API and its implementation. What I'd see is write a service file in your implementation named `/META-INF/services/com.google.inject.Module` that contains each Guice module you want to be instanciated. In your API Guice module have the following code: `for (Module m: ServiceLoader.load(Module.class)) install(m);`. But I do NOT recommend this. I recommend a clean separation between API and its implementations.

Comment: This is Java SPI, right? And what about Guice SPI? I don't know how to use it in my case. Because my root guice module in IMPL, and this is install all other modules. I might create this module by reflection, without java SPI - it is simply.

Comment: You know that without concrete example, we're a bit stuck at what you have and what you need. I tried to show you how to properly decouple your API from your impl without each other having any impact on the other.  But you've written nothing that we can use. I've tried to guess what you want, but apparently I'm wrong. Just so you know, Guice SPI is used only to create Guice extensions. Your best way is the "Java SPI", not the "Guice SPI". I mentioned the latter only to show you it's not rare to have SPIs.